# Commands paths in TeXMaker on Mac OS X - with 'could not start the command' error

Tags: texmaker, mactex

I'm new to LaTex and tried to run some templates on TexMaker until I realized that I had to set up the paths under Preferences. I've already downloaded MacTex 2017.

I've been trying to find some recent posts on here but most are older or I have tried some answers but it either doesn't work or I don't understand what they are saying.

[image: This is the error message that I am getting]

Currently, this is what my set up is like and this is the [template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/deedy-resume?nocdn=true) that I am trying to use. Please help!

[image]

Comment: A wild guess, but try to remove the quotation marks from `"pdflatex"`. Mine doesn't have these, but I don't know if it is a OS requirement.

Comment: It still doesn't work :( I think it's a setup error? But I am so new that I know nothing...